SNMP error: No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
I cannot access the MIB file with an snmpwalk or get.
This is the MIB file:
TEST-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
    Integer32, OBJECT-TYPE, enterprises, MODULE-IDENTITY
        FROM SNMPv2-SMI
    OBJECT-GROUP
        FROM SNMPv2-CONF;

testObjects MODULE-IDENTITY
    LAST-UPDATED "202405150000Z"
    ORGANIZATION "YourOrganization"
    CONTACT-INFO
         "Your Contact Info"
    DESCRIPTION
         "Defines objects for testing purposes."
    ::= { enterprises 8888 }

testInteger OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      Integer32
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
      "An integer object for testing."
    ::= { testObjects 1 }

-- Define an object group
testObjectGroup OBJECT-GROUP
    OBJECTS {
        testInteger
    }
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "A group containing objects for testing purposes."
    ::= { testObjects 2 }

END

I have already updated the permission on snmpd.conf and tried to reach it directly with the OID.

Writing up a MIB document like this won’t have any impact on an SNMP agent like snmpd. You should read a book or find a tutorial with search engines.
